# I cannot compile any tex file with pdflatex? (problem started today) How can I solve it?

Tags: miktex, compiling, ubuntu, compilation-error

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

I downloaded `miktex console` 2 days ago to download some latex packages I wasn't able to. It was working fine. Today it was also working. But all of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
pdflatex: A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
pdflatex: Data: error="invalid value definition", file="/home/user/.miktex/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini", line="6"

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now it doesnt compile even empty basic tex files. When I try to remove or purge miktex I get this message:

```
(Reading database ... 344029 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing miktex (21.6-bionic1) ...
miktexsetup: A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
miktexsetup: Data: error="invalid value definition", file="/home/user/.miktex/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini", line="6"
dpkg: error processing package miktex (--remove):
 installed miktex package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 miktex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also when I try `sudo apt-get update`  I get:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository
 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Please Help me solve this issue.

**Edit 1:** `sudo apt-get install -f` doesn't work either.

**Edit 2:** The contents of `/home/user/.miktex/texmfs/config/miktex/config/miktex.ini` file is below:

```
;;; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!


[MPM]
AuthToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJNUE0vNC4zIiwianRpIjoiNmY1ZWQ2NzYtM2Y0ZC00ZjZjLWE1YTUtYjQ0ODA3ZGZjODJjIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMwMDk2NzkzLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiTVBNLzQuMyIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6IlVzZXIiLCJuYmYiOjE2MzAwOTY3OTIsImV4cCI6MTYzMDA5NzA5MiwiaXNzIjoiTWlLVGVYb3JnQVBJIiwiYXVkIjoiTWlLVGVYb3JnQVBJIn0.1PRiYypYf1rCoi0HMFEuthyWi8RIB1axRNadgabvIgQ
nQVBJIn0.R4v3h9AG2DINggjnRakKJmCL56AFH3xTfNIs1W9hknY
AuthTokenNotValidAfter=1630097092
AutoInstall=1
LastUserUpdate=1630028723
LastUserUpdateCheck=1630027827
LastUserUpdateDb=1630027827

[Setup]
LastUserDiagnose=1630027828
```

Comment: And what is at line 6 of the MiKTeX.ini?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is `nQVBJIn0.R4v3h9AG2DINggjnRakKJmCL56AFH3xTfNIs1W9hknY
` I don't know if it means anything? I also added the rest of the file as an edit above.

Comment: Probably the file is broken,  ask at the miktex github.

Comment: any particular reason to be using miktex on linux?

Comment: What happend between the last time it compiled, and the first time you've got errors?

Comment: @MS-SPO nothing really I normally compile after writing something and read it like every 2 minutes. I compiled like 50 times and it worked normal. And at 51th it did not compile anymore and gave that error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so I have only linux on my computer. I was trying to download some of the packages and I saw a video saying that the easiest way to download these packages was to download miktex console and let it download these packages itself. That's why I downloaded it

Comment: Strange. Ok, here is a way of thinking, to may be better perceive what's going on. // TASK: Guarantee that ANY miktex operation will fail ANYTIME ANYWHERE ALL the time. // RESTRICTIONS: Use only, what IS already available, like OS, computer, network connection, .tex files, .ini files, .config files, .log files, permissions etc. // Compile hypothesises, which are compliant with TASK and RESTRICTIONS. Try validating those hypothesis.